# Python with HTML front-end

Tags: python, html

I have a Python script that runs on my Linux server. I want to make a simple HTML page to be the "front-end" of my script. It will just take 2 values from a web form (that user will insert acessing the webpage) and send them to the Python script on background as variables, then Python will operate with these values and make all the stuff works.

Is it possible?

Tks !

Comment: This is how CGI works. What have you tried?

Comment: See [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/), or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), the web framework built on top of it. Alternatively, you could go with [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/), another minimalist web framework, or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (although it might be overkill in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need CherryPy

[CherryPy documentation](https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You have to use the web frameworks such as Django to do this.

You can receive the input from the HTML file with name attribute in the HTML file and if you return back the output you can use the value attribute.

Web Frameworks use Handlers to receive and post the data to the HTML form.

In order to use the web frameworks, you need to install them in your server like you installed python in your Linux server.

Comment: You certainly do _not_ need a framework.